# Set theory related objective questions.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> If $X$ and $Y$ are two non-empty finite sets and $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to X$ are mappings such that $g\circ f:X\to X$ is a surjective (i.e., onto) map, then
>
> - (A) $f$ must be one-to-one.
> - (B) $f$ must be onto.
> - (C) $g$ must be one-to-one.
> - (D) $X$ and $Y$ must have the same number of elements.

If $g\circ f$ is onto then I know only that $g$ is onto but this is not given in options. Please help me  to find correct options. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Because $X$ is finite, if $g\circ f$ is surjective, it must also be one-to-one.

Comment: how to use finiteness to prove one one .

Comment: @neelkanth: Show that if $g\circ f$ is not one-to-one, then there is a proper subset $Z$ of $X$ such that $(g\circ f)[Z]=X$. But then $|Z|<|X|$, since $Z$ is a proper subset of the finite set $X$, but on the other hand the bijection shows that $|Z|=|X|$. Oops!

Answer (score 0):

Take $X=\{1\}$ and $Y=\{1,2\}$. Define $f(x)=1$ and $g(y)=1$. Then $g \circ f : \{1\} \rightarrow \{1\}$ is onto. Now you can see that B,C,D are NOT true. So A is the most likely choice. Now follow @Brian M. Scott's answer.